# Hide/show divs when scrolling a fixed height div

Tags: html, scroll

I'm creating a PHP-based site with a text box. Often the text field overflows, so I'm making it fixed height with an auto y-overflow.

To indicate more text below the visible space, I'd like to fade out the bottom of the text. There are many techniques to do this. The way I'd like to go is for a div tag on top of the text, containing a copy of the background image which fades to transparent. Problem is when you hit the bottom of the scroll, I want this div tag to hide, then show again when scrolling up, and in turn a hidden div at the top of show when scrolling down, and hide when back at the top of the page.

I've adapted a jsfiddle, but not having much look. Any ideas what I've missed?

the original js is here http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ZyKar/1067/

and my adapted version is here http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/1702/

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    //Show element after user scrolls 800px
    var y = $('.content').scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        $('.bottom').fadeOut();
        $('.top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.bottom').fadeIn();
        $('.top').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

I had the fades working until I tried to adapt the scroll to be based on the scroll within the content div rather than the whole body.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you attached the scroll to the content div instead?

Do this:

```
$('.content').scroll(function () {
```

Instead of this:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/1703/)

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont know if i understand your problem completely, but it sounds that you want somethink like this:

```
$('.content').scroll(function () {
```

Instead of

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
```

Since you want to know how far the user scrolled ni your element and not on the whole page, do you?

Updated your [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/1704/)